# RDP configuration across two of 3 monitors, while one monitor is an ultrawide?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have 3 monitors, a 34" ultrawide in the center, and 2 27" monitors on the sides. I want to run RDP sessions on the main monitor (the ultrawide), and one of the side monitors. In the past, I was able to do this no problem when I was using the 2 27" monitors and my laptop screen. Now, when I try to configure RDP to use specific monitors with the `selectedmonitors` property, I can only get the main monitor (ultrawide) to run the RDP session. Even with multiple monitors selected, I still just get a full screen RDP on the ultrawide.

Resolutions are 1920x1080 on the 27" monitors, and 3440x1440 on the 34" ultrawide.

Any ideas?

Here is my RDP config:

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:1
selectedmonitors:s:1,2
desktopwidth:i:3440
desktopheight:i:1440
session bpp:i:15
winposstr:s:0,3,97,109,2033,1227
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:1
networkautodetect:i:0
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:1
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:1
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:MYREMOTECOMPUTER
audiomode:i:2
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:1
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
drivestoredirect:s:*
camerastoredirect:s:*
devicestoredirect:s:*
```